# Error handling with inputdlg

Tags: matlab

Below is an input dialog box I'm using in a program. Does anyone know
how to "nicely" handle the case when the user input is not a number?
Also, if the number is outside the range minlev - maxlev then the
error dialog pops up, but you cannot press the OK button because the
input dialog pops up in front of it. Does anyone know how to fix
this?

```
RVP= 1;


while ( RVP )

prompt = {'Enter the corridor width (1050-1400mm) :'};

dlg_title = 'Input';

num_lines=1;

answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);

    if(str2num(answer{1})<1050 || (str2num(answer{1})>1400))
       errordlg('Number is out of range');

    else 
        w1 = (2*answer{1}-1050-1400)/(1400-1050)


    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isnumeric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html). Then you can re-call the inputdlg after the error dialog.

To keep the errordlg box from being covered up, use uiwait.

```
while ( RVP )
    prompt = {'Enter the corridor width (1050-1400mm) :'};
    dlg_title = 'Input';
    num_lines=1;
    answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);
    if ~isnumeric(answer) || (str2num(answer{1})<1050 || (str2num(answer{1})>1400))
        uiwait(errordlg('Number is out of range'));
        answer = inputdlg({'Please enter a valid input (1050-1400mm) :'},...
                          dlg_title,num_lines);
    end
        w1 = (2*answer{1}-1050-1400)/(1400-1050)
end
```